# Верстка таблицы (last-child и first-child)

Tags: html, css, table

Пока в таблице все ячейки одного размера, всё работает отлично. Но, при объединении ячеек, начинают неправильно определяться `:first-child` и `:last-child`.

По логике они конечно определяются правильно, но как исправить CSS, чтобы этого не происходило?

```css
table {
  //font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

th,
td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  border-color: white;
  background: #AAB8D7;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
  background: #AAB8D7;
  font-weight: bold;
}

th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-right: none;
}

tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

tr td:first-child {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(n+2) {
  background: #C8DEEE;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(n+2) {
  background: #DDEBF4;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Попытка</th>
    <th>8 ребер</th>
    <th>12 ребер</th>
    <th>4 блока 2x2x2</th>
    <th>6 центров</th>
    <th>Время сборки</th>
    <th>Среднее время</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mini 2x2+4x4</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>7'28"</td>
    <td>7'17"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>6'10"</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>9'24"</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>7'21"</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Попытка</th>
    <th>8 ребер</th>
    <th>12 ребер</th>
    <th>4 блока 2x2x2</th>
    <th>6 центров</th>
    <th>Время сборки</th>
    <th>Среднее время</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">mini 2x2+4x4</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>7'28"</td>
    <td rowspan="4">7'17"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>6'10"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>9'24"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>7'21"</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: вручную классы прописать остается.

Comment: @teran, по углам?

Comment: Ну если через стили никак, то вариант конечно, но не приятный, там штук 100+ таблиц и ручками, естественно, не интересно, нужно будет регулярку писать (не простую) и файлы перелопачивать (

Comment: были бы таблицы с `thead => th` было бы проще. потом стиль к `td:first-child[rowspan]` написали бы да и дело с концом. Собственно, вы это и так можете, не ясно правда, решит ли это вашу проблем полностью.

Comment: а.пардоньте,  у вас есть `th`. Ну если нет необходимости реализовать это для обоих видов таблиц одновременно, то тогда вроде можно без проблем на основании атрибута `rowspan`

Comment: `th` то есть да... хотелось бы универсальности, т.к. объединённые ячейки не всегда вначале и вконце, а в некоторых и вовсе отсутствуют. А что есть такой аттрибут не знал, спасибо

Comment: в смысле не знали, если у вас в таблицах используется `<td rowspan="4">`, а в квадратных скобках в CSS в принципе указываются наименования или значения атрибутов

Comment: @teran, не знал, что "в квадратных скобках в CSS в принципе указываются наименования или значения атрибутов". Как-то никогда не сталкивался.

Comment: тогда вам бы почитать про [селекторы](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors) :)

Comment: @teran, В общем, даже если классы прописать вручную, универсально у меня не получилось сделать :( можно маленький примерчик?

Answer (score 2):

1. ##### Скругление углов

   Если скругления только на углах таблицы, то нужно указывать радиусы именно у тега `<table>`, а не у ячеек. Некоторые браузеры некорректно работают со свойством `overflow: hidden` указанным для `<table>`, тогда необходимо обернуть таблицу в дополнительный блок и задать ему `border-radius` и `overflow`.
2. ##### Ячейки заголовков

   Теги `<th>` - это такие же ячейки, как и `<td>`, с той лишь разницей, что имеют некоторые стили по умолчанию (выравнивание текста по центру, жирность шрифта и т.п. - зависит от браузера), а также они нужны для семантики. Поэтому можно использовать `<th>` наравне с обычными `<td>` в любом месте таблицы (т.е. не только в `<thead>` или в первой `<tr>`).
3. ##### Границы ячеек

   Браузеры давно имеют хорошую поддержку свойства `box-shadow`, поэтому желательно использовать его вместо `border`. Это зачастую позволяет избежать различных смещений (и, как следствие, подгонки), так как тень накладывается и не влияет на размеры элементов.

   В данном случае, нужно сместить тень (или оставить только те части рамки) так, чтобы у ячеек остались видимыми границы только сверху и слева. Почему именно так? Ячейки заголовков всегда первые, тогда как количество обычных ячеек и их индексы могут меняться. Следовательно, намного проще уточнить стили именно заголовочных ячеек.

В примере ниже, таблицы используют одни и те же стили, но структура их различна и, при этом, всё отображается корректно:

```css
table {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

th,
td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  border-color: white;
  background: #AAB8D7;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

tr:first-child th {
  border-top: none;
}

th:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-left: none;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #C8DEEE;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #DDEBF4;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Попытка</th>
    <th>8 ребер</th>
    <th>12 ребер</th>
    <th>4 блока 2x2x2</th>
    <th>6 центров</th>
    <th>Время сборки</th>
    <th>Среднее время</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>7'28"</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">mini 2x2+4x4</th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>6'10"</td>
    <td rowspan="3">7'17"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>9'24"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>7'21"</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Попытка</th>
    <th>8 ребер</th>
    <th>12 ребер</th>
    <th>4 блока 2x2x2</th>
    <th>6 центров</th>
    <th>Время сборки</th>
    <th>Среднее время</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="4">mini 2x2+4x4</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>7'28"</td>
    <td rowspan="4">7'17"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>6'10"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>9'24"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>7'21"</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Раскопки древностей идут успешно? :) Удалось проветрится сегодня?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: Раскопки в разгаре)) Но, некогда - подработка время отнимает.